# How to get data from array of jsonarray from a PHP?

Tags: android, arrays, json

This is the output I am getting from my server script:

```
{"task_id":"1","task_create_time":"2015-08-09 22:48:25","task_end_time":"0000-00-00 ``00:00:00","service_id":"2","task_status":"1","user_id":"1","user_email":"r@gmail.com","user_name":"rr","user_mobile":"1234567890"}{"task_id":"3","task_create_time":"2015-08-13 00:23:54","task_end_time":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","service_id":"2","task_status":"1","user_id":"2","user_email":null,"user_name":null,"user_mobile":null}
```

I want to convert this output to a custom list in Android, but I am getting many errors. My code:

```
try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url_jobdetail);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();

    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), “pass”,
    // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (Exception e) {

}
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line + "\n");         
}
is.close();

result = sb.toString();
```

this the error i am getting

```
08-13 12:42:34.935: I/InputMethodManager(23564): handleMessage: MSG_SET_ACTIVE true, was false
```

08-13 12:42:39.463: D/AbsListView(23564): checkAbsListViewlLogProperty get invalid command
08-13 12:42:39.478: D/AndroidRuntime(23564): Shutting down VM
08-13 12:42:39.478: W/dalvikvm(23564): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40cb49c0)
08-13 12:42:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(23564): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 12:42:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(23564): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.OnDeOS.ondeos_internal/com.OnDeOS.ondeos_internal.jobs}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-13 12:42:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(23564):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
08-13 12:42:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(23564):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
08-13 12:42:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(23564):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
08-13 12:42:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(23564):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
08-13 12:42:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(23564):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
08-13 12:42:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(23564):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
08-13 12:42:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(23564):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
08-13 12:42:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(23564):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 12:42:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(23564):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-13 12:42:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(23564):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
08-13 12:42:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(23564):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
08-13 12:42:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(23564):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-13 12:42:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(23564): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-13 12:42:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(23564):    at com.OnDeOS.ondeos_internal.jobs.onCreate(jobs.java:67)
08-13 12:42:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(23564):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
08-13 12:42:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(23564):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
08-13 12:42:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(23564):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
08-13 12:42:39.499: E/AndroidRuntime(23564):    ... 11 more

Comment: possible duplicate of [filter json array php by string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765073/filter-json-array-php-by-string)

Comment: I recommend to try to use Gson to se/deserialize your JSON, or Jackson make it too, are easy to understand. And the other is to use Volley from Google or Retrofit by Square to make your requests, arent hard to implement and lets you handle pretty/faster/extensible way this kind of things. Regards

Answer (score -1):

Are you able to get the response in your "result" variable?  If so, you can parse it like so:

```
JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

Comment: i am not getting any value from the following code. the code follow get stop at this point


BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);

Comment: @AlagarRaja Post the Logcat to your question. If you have erros, we need details about them to be able to help you.