# How to filter an array in PHP by fields with empty values and multiple criteria?

Tags: php, arrays, filtering

My API call returns the following JSON output before `json_decode`:

```
{
"projects": [
        {
            "project_id": 00000001,
            "name": "A title",
            "price": "0.99",
            "country": "US",
            "platform_types": [
                "android_phone",
                "ios_phone",
                "ios_tablet",
                "android_kindle",
                "android_tablet",
                "desktop"
            ],
            "comment": "A text of a comment"
        }
        {
            "project_id": 00000002,
            "name": "Another title",
            "price": "1.03",
            "country": "US",
            "platform_types": [
                "android_phone",
                "ios_phone",
                "ios_tablet",
                "android_kindle",
                "android_tablet",
                "desktop"
            ],
            "comment": "Another text of a comment"
        }
    ]
}
```

The following code parses the multi-level json and shows the whole projects list:

```
$json = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$result = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($result['projects'] as $project) {
    $project_id = $project['project_id'];
    $name = $project['name'];
    $price = $project['price'];
    $country = $project['country'];
    #no values for the fields, that's why commented
    #$android_phone = $project['platform_types']['android_phone'];
    #$ios_phone = $project['platform_types']['ios_phone'];
    #$ios_tablet = $project['platform_types']['ios_tablet'];
    #$android_kindle = $project['platform_types']['android_kindle'];
    #$android_tablet = $project['platform_types']['android_tablet'];
    #$desktop = $project['platform_types']['desktop'];
    $comment = $project['comment'];
    echo $project_id,'<br>',$name,'<br>',$price,'<br>',$country,'<br>',$comment,'<br>';
}
```

I got the following output:

```
00000001
A title
0.99
US
A text of a comment

00000002
Another title
1.03
US
Another text of a comment
```

**The questions are:**

1. How to list available device types (the fields have names only and no values)?
2. How to filter the array based on certain criteria (price must be equal or higher $1.00)?
3. How to filter elements based on fields without values (show projects just for Android devices)?

Comment: You should have a look at https://php.net/array_filter

Comment: 1. Use `foreach` (just like you did for the "projects" array). 2. array_filter(). N.B. This actually has nothing to do with JSON. You're not filtering JSON. Your data ceased to be JSON after you decoded it. Now it's just a PHP array structure, so you should search online for solutions which involve filtering PHP arrays. I'll update the question for you.

Comment: As for the price is that possible to use suggested or similar function from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765073/filter-json-array-php-by-string) and put it before `json_decode` just to cut json callback?

Comment: `$project['platform_types']['android_phone']` doesn't match the JSON. `'android_phone'` is a value, not an array key.

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo, thank you for explaining. I realized my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Question 1

to list all the available device types per project as a json you should access it's corresponding tree

```php
foreach($result['projects'] as $project) {
    $project_device_types = $project['plateform_type'];
    echo '<pre>'.$project_device_types.'<pre>';
}
```

#### Question 2

to filter the array use [array_filter][1] in

```php
$filtered = array_filter($result['projects'], function($project) {
    if($project['price'] >= 90) {
      return true
    }
});
// use it instead of the $result variable
foreach($filtered as $project) {
    $project_id = $project['project_id'];
    $name = $project['name'];
    $price = $project['price'];
}
```

#### Question 3

you can follow the exact pattern as the second question and that is by using array_filter so eg. let's say you want only the android devices

```php
array_filter($result['projects'], function($project) {
    if(in_array($project['platform_types'], "Android")) { // check if the plateform type include android by using [in_array][1]
      return true
    }
});
```

> NB: in_array is case sensitive so make sure that the capitalization is correct

Comment: where in my code should I insert `$filtered = array_filter(...)`?

Comment: I updated the second answer check it

Comment: many thanks! It's awesome! What if I would like to combine two or more filters (user's filters to show only what they need)? Is that better way to use functions? Any example to use filters with functions?

Comment: I'd say calling array_filter() is a good example of using filters with functions ;). You can probably run the first filter on the unfiltered data, and then run the second filter on the result from the first operation. Or, build a filter function that implements both filters simultaneously. But that tends to be less maintainable in the long run.

Comment: you can use the approach that @TorbjörnStabo suggested should work like a charm

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo, what I want to do is that users will have a GUI where they can apply either one or several filters. It makes the task a bit more complicated. Need use GET or POST and send variables that call some functions. I can easily handle it with MySQL queries, but JSON is different and always dynamic. What approach would you suggest?

Comment: @Abdusalammohamed, `echo '<pre>'.$project_device_types.'<pre>';` returns "Array", not the list of available devices, how to make a list, comma separated?

Comment: Made it work to list all the devices, not just an array: `$project_device_types = $project['platform_types'];
$string = implode(',', (array) $project_device_types);
echo $string,'<br>';`

Comment: Yeah @SergeyRusskikh thought you had an array to work with, good job

Comment: @Abdusalammohamed, as for question 2, I believe, there's something wrong with code `$filtered = array_filter($result['projects'], function($project) {
    if($project['price'] >= 90) {
      return true
    }
});` as it doesn't work itself even without using `foreach($filtered as $project)`. Will you please review it and update?

Comment: @Abdusalammohamed, as for question 2 it was just a syntax error in your code, instead of `return true` you should use `return true;`.

Comment: Yes i work with python a lot that is why lol, you got it